# Probability Problem of a Lord and his 5 Friends

Tags: probability

I have the following Exercise

> A Lord is inviting five friends of his to dinner, each one for a specific night of the week (no one is invited
> for the weekend).
> He writes five different letters and hands them to his shortsighted butler to deliver them
> to the mailman. 
> The butler, who can’t distinguish the names of the recipients of the letters, puts them at
> random inside the five envelopes he has in his possession.
> What is the probability that none of the Lord’s
> friends show up at the right time?

**What I did until now:**
there are 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120 ways to distribute the letters to the envelopes.
And I was thinking about all the cases where we distribute it the way, that at least one would be correct (it was easier to imagine for me)
I got
1 case where all are correct
45 cases where just one is correct
20 cases where 2 are correct
10 cases where 3 are correct

There are no cases where 4 are correct because then the 5th must be also correct.

I substracted the amouth of cases from 120 and got 44

so the Probability that none of the Friends would show up at the right time would be
( 44/120 ) * 100 = 36.667 %

Is it correct like this ? Is there an easier way to compute the probability?

Comment: It might help to look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement , the name for permutations without fixed points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could derive the end result directly from first principles,
applying inclusion-exclusion, viz

No. of derangements = All permutations - at least one right  + at least two right  - at least three right + ...

$= 5! - \binom514! +\binom523!-\binom532! + \binom541! -\binom550! = 44$

A nifty formula is $D_n = round(\frac{n!}{e})$

But do look up derangements and learn in more detail